# Why does it use "if will"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

From *2 Broke Girls*:

> I'm going to the prom with Brandon, if his dad will lend him the car.

[image]

Why does the quote use "if ... will"?

After reading [this ELL question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181572/using-will-after-if), I think it should be *if ... would*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Will" does not always function as a future marker; it can be used to mean "be willing to." So your sentence amounts to "I'm going to the prom with Brandon, if his dad **is willing to** lend him the car."